# How to apply Word Net Lemmatizer on pyspark data frame?

Tags: pyspark, nltk, lemmatization

I'm trying to apply WordNet Lemmatization on one of my Data Frame columns.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|             removed|stars|
+--------------------+-----+
|[today, second, t...|  1.0|
|[ill, first, admi...|  4.0|
|[believe, things,...|  1.0|
|[great, lunch, to...|  4.0|
|[weve, huge, slim...|  5.0|
|[plumbsmart, prov...|  5.0|
```

So each row is the list of tokens. Now I want to lemmatize each token.

I've tried with:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() 

df_lemma= df_removed.select(lemmatizer.lemmatize('removed')) 
df_lemma.show()
```

I did not get any error message, but my dataframe did not change.

```
+--------------------+
|             removed|
+--------------------+
|[today, second, t...|
|[ill, first, admi...|
|[believe, things,...|
|[great, lunch, to...|
|[weve, huge, slim...|
|[plumbsmart, prov...|
```

Is there any error in my code? How should I apply lemmatizer?